# how to perform any task on clicking main menubutton

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have a menu heading, on clicking on which sub menu items are displayed. The set on action function is working for the sub menu items but not for the main menu. I wanted to perform some task on just clicking on the main menu along with the drop down list of sub menu items. Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example about how to catch events for the menu, the submenu and the menu items:

```
public class MenuActionDemo extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Menus");
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250, Color.WHITE);

        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();

        // main menu item
        Menu menu = new Menu("Item");
        menu.showingProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {

                if( newValue) {
                    System.out.println( "Main menu item showing");
                } else {
                    System.out.println( "Main menu item closing");
                }

            }
        });

        // sub menu
        Menu subMenu = new Menu("Submenu");
        subMenu.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                if( event.getTarget() == subMenu) {
                    System.out.println("Submenu clicked");
                }

            }
        });

        // sub menu item
        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem("Submenu Item 1");
        menuItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                System.out.println("Submenu Item 1 clicked");

            }
        });
        subMenu.getItems().add(menuItem);

        // add items to main menu
        menu.getItems().add(subMenu);

        menuBar.prefWidthProperty().bind(primaryStage.widthProperty());
        menuBar.getMenus().add(menu);

        root.getChildren().add(menuBar);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: If the menu do not have any sub menu item, then showingproperty method will not work. Is there any other way to perform task with such menu?

Comment: It does work. Do you have a full example where it doesn't work for you?

Comment: I have menu which has no sub menu item. When I applied your showingpropertycode, it resulted into nothing.

Comment: My code is tested, it works. Have you tried only my example? And do you mean you have a MenuBar with a Menu and no MenuItem objects? To make things short: Use an ANY EventHandler like this addEventHandler(Event.ANY, event -> System.out.println(event)); and you can see what gets fired and what doesn't. By the way, if you have a simple Menu with no MenuItem objects, then nothing gets fired. But from a usability point of view you shouldn't have that anyway.

Comment: My code requirement is such that I need an empty menu. But I'm unable to perform any action with the code you suggested.

Comment: In that case I suggest you rather create a toolbar instead of a menu.